# GraphQL - What are best practices for nested queries?

Tags: javascript, graphql, strapi

I’m having an issue and not sure if it’s my understanding of GraphQL or an issue with the platform i'm using (Strapi).

Context: For my use case, I want to show a portfolio of projects (or 'cases'). Each case has a group of contributors that worked on it. This field is separate to the author / creator of a case. The issue is that for technical reasons, a Case's contents is split into two types: draft and published. Which means when I want to get all articles, I need to go one level 'deeper' in the nesting to also include the array of contributors.

```
Case
-- Draft
---- Caseinfo
------ Contributors

-- Published
---- CaseInfo
------ Contributors
```

Currently I can get allCase and get the contents of each case, plus its contributors:

```
// Used in Gatsby's `<StaticQuery />`
// This works fine.

  allCase {
    edges {
      node {
        contributors {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But when I try to include the nesting

```
  allCase(filter: {status: {eq: "published"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        published_contents {
          id
          title
          // Cannot query field "contributors" on type "CasePublished_contents".
          contributors {
              name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So as soon as the contributors field is nested one level deeper, I cannot query it?

Conceptually, can you make a deeply nested GraphQL query like this and expect it to follow all relational content types “down the tree”?

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your graphql schema. Is `Case` a union of `Draft` and `Published`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot query a field of a higher-level entity on the lower-level. The `contributors` field only exists on the node (a `CaseInfo`?) and not on the `CasePublished_contents` type.

Just don't nest it:

```
allCase(filter: {status: {eq: "published"}}) {
  edges {
    node {
      published_contents {
        id
        title
      }
      contributors {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But published_contents and draft_contents may have different contributors... a use case may be if I have a published version that says "4 contributors" but I start making an edit in draft state that changes is to "3"

Comment: @LucasArundell Well, according to your schema neither of them has `contributors`. If you need to change that, please show us how you are building/configuring your schema, not (just) the queries.

Comment: Oh gotcha. SO i'm using Strapi - a CMS which generates the schema. My (limited) understanding was that as I create any fields within a "Case", they were automatically showing up in my query. Maybe something to do with the fact that it's a nested relational one